# Inequalities for generalized means

Tags: calculus, statistics, inequality, exponentiation, holder-inequality

Given a set of $n$ observations $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, the power mean is defined as
$$M_p = \Big(\frac{x_1^p+\cdots + x_n^p}{n}\Big)^{1/p}.$$
Likewise, the exponential mean is defined as
$$m_p = \log_p\Big(\frac{p^{x_1}+\cdots + p^{x_n}}{n}\Big).$$
The logarithm is in base $p> 0$. If $p\rightarrow 0$, then $m_p$ tends to the minimum observation. If $p\rightarrow \infty$, then $m_p$ tends to the maximum observation. If $p\rightarrow 1$, then $m_p$ tends to the arithmetic mean. Note that $m_p$ (unlike $M_p$) is defined even if any of the observations is negative. For details, see [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/alternative-to-the-arithmetic-geometric-and-harmonic-means).

I am wondering if the following results are correct:

- If $p <  q$, then $m_p \leq m_q$, and $m_p = m_q$ if and only if $x_1 =   ... = x_n$.
- If $p > 1$, then $m_p \leq M_p$, and $m_p = M_p$ if and only if $x_1 = ...   = x_n$.

**Hint for the first inequality**

The second one is not true, see Michael's answer below. The first one may or may not be true, but the following could help settle the question. I used WolframAlpha to compute the derivative of $m_p$ with respect to $p$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate%20%28log%28p%5Ex%2Bp%5Ey%2Bp%5Ez%2Bp%5Ew%29-%20%28log%204%29%29%2F%28log%20p%29%20wrt%20p).

$$m'_p =\frac{dm_p}{dp}
=\frac{1}{p \log p}\cdot\Big[\frac{x_1p^{x_1}+\cdots+x_np^{x_n}}{p_1^{x_1}+\cdots+p_n^{x_n}}-m_p\Big].$$

The next step is to prove (or disprove) that $m'_p \geq 0$. Since $\log p > 0$ if $p>1$ and $\log p < 0$ if $p<1$, it suffices to prove that

$$\frac{x_1p^{x_1}+\cdots+x_np^{x_n}}{p_1^{x_1}+\cdots+p_n^{x_n}} \geq m_p
 \mbox{ if } p>1,
$$
$$\frac{x_1p^{x_1}+\cdots+x_np^{x_n}}{p_1^{x_1}+\cdots+p_n^{x_n}} \leq m_p
 \mbox{ if } p<1.
$$

The derivative $m'_p$  is well approximated by a power function, positive everywhere for $p\geq0$, suggesting that the first inequality is correct. A remarkable fact is the following:

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 1} m'_p=\frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i-x_j)^2 \geq 0.$$
I haven't explicitly computed that limit in general, instead I used WolfFramAlpha (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28%28x%20p%5Ex%20%2B%20y%20p%5Ey%20%2B%20z%20p%5Ez%20%2B%20w%20p%5Ew%20%2B%20u%20p%5Eu%29%2F%28p%5Ex%20%2B%20p%5Ey%20%2Bp%5Ez%20%2B%20p%5Ew%20%2B%20p%5Eu%29%20-%20%28log%28p%5Ex%20%2B%20p%5Ey%20%2Bp%5Ez%20%2B%20p%5Ew%20%2Bp%5Eu%29-log%285%29%29%2F%28log%20p%29%29%2F%28log%20p%29%20as%20p-%3E1)) to compute it for $n=2,3,4,5$. I've found a pattern, and generalized it to any $n$; see also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370095/remarkable-limit-involving-m-p-log-ppx-1-cdots-px-n-log-pn).
Since $m_\infty = \max(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ we also have $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}m'_p = 0$. It also seems that if the $x_i's$ are not all identical, then $\lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+} m'_p=+\infty$. To complete the proof of the first inequality, one may proceed recursively on $n$.

Comment: I hope we work with positive numbers. Or maybe not?

Comment: We can restrict ourselves to positive numbers, I thought about that. We have too anyway when making comparisons between $m_p$ and $M_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second inequality is wrong.

Try $n=3$, $p=e$, $x_1=x_2=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and $x_3=2$.

In this case $$M_e-m_e=-0.000719...<0$$

Comment: Thank you Michael.